# Pause the GACUTIL.exe listing

Tags: .net, windows, gacutil

On my Windows System, I have over 3000 registered libraries in my GAC. When I use gacutil /l the list is too large to fit in my command output window. I need to be able to browse through to see if my library is in the list, is there a way to pause the listing or to save it to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How people forget. You can pipe the output from any command to the `more` command. This then does paging of the output:

```
gacutil /l | more
```

Each time it's filled the screen, it will prompt with `--more--`. Press space to see the next page.

There are lots of options for working with `more` too (output from `more /?`):

```
Displays output one screen at a time.

MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]] < [drive:][path]filename
command-name | MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]]
MORE /E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n] [files]

    [drive:][path]filename  Specifies a file to display one
                            screen at a time.

    command-name            Specifies a command whose output
                            will be displayed.

    /E      Enable extended features
    /C      Clear screen before displaying page
    /P      Expand FormFeed characters
    /S      Squeeze multiple blank lines into a single line
    /Tn     Expand tabs to n spaces (default 8)

            Switches can be present in the MORE environment
            variable.

    +n      Start displaying the first file at line n

    files   List of files to be displayed. Files in the list
            are separated by blanks.

    If extended features are enabled, the following commands
    are accepted at the -- More -- prompt:

    P n     Display next n lines
    S n     Skip next n lines
    F       Display next file
    Q       Quit
    =       Show line number
    ?       Show help line
    <space> Display next page
    <ret>   Display next line
```

Comment: It is so UNIX like :)

Comment: Change "any command" to "almost any command". Some console applications explicitly open "CONOUT$" (the active console screen buffer) or create a new screen buffer. Redirecting stdout to a pipe has no effect on these cases.

Comment: Damien, thanks for the explanation I learnt something I will use in the future. It answered the question on as how to pause the listing.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `gacutil /l > output.txt` it will write the output of the command to the file named `output.txt` in whatever folder you are currently in.

Comment: Dear Scott this was extremely useful. It is probably common knowledge but when I focused on a problem it is hard to even know how to phrase the question. I picked the answer from Damian_The_Unbeliever because he addressed the first part of the question I asked how to pause the listing. I could have equally picked your answer. Thank you so much for your response it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list by specifying the assembly name.

For example,

> GacUtil /l System.Data.Linq

Lists 2 assemblies named "System.Data.Linq" on my system, version 3.5 and version 4.0.